# How to use state value as key to access value in array?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, state

With this line I can display teams name by accesing an objects value "name" in array "teams":

```
<div>Selected teams name: {teams[1].name}</div>
```

**How in the same way I can acces specific object using state instead of hard coded number?**

For now I am trying this line (in code commented). But it doesn't work although the state's "selectedCheckbox" value is also "1":

```
<div>Selected teams name: {teams[{selectedCheckbox}].name}</div>
```

Link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/only-one-checkbox-forked-qxjoz6?file=/src/App.js

The code is following:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [selectedCheckbox, setSelectedCheckbox] = React.useState(1);
      const teams = [
        { id: "1", name: "Kittens", pointCount: 3 },
        { id: "2", name: "Lions", pointCount: 8 },
        { id: "3", name: "Fishys", pointCount: 13 }
      ];
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h2>Select team!</h2>
          {teams.map(({ name, pointCount }, index) => (
            <div>
              <div>{name}</div>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={selectedCheckbox === index}
                onChange={() => setSelectedCheckbox(index)}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
          <div>Selected checkbox number: {selectedCheckbox}</div>
          <div>Selected teams name: {teams[1].name}</div>
          {/* <div>Selected teams name: {teams[{selectedCheckbox}].name}</div> */}
        </div>
      );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access an object in an array using state, you can use the state value as the array index.
That's why you should use it like this:

```
<div>Selected teams name: {teams[selectedCheckbox].name}</div>
```

Comment: I had a feeling that it was that simple! =D